# Redirect user to the previous route after a successful login - Flow-Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

Using Meteor and FlowRouter for my website, I'm trying to get the following result.

A user receive a mail containing a link to a specific page of our website.

- if the user is already logged on the website, he access the page successfully
- if he's not, he's redirected to the login page. But I would like my user to be redirected to the page he was supposed to access at first after the successful login.

I put my route in `PrivateRoute.js`. This way I can redirect my user to the login page if he's not logged in. But I don't know how to redirect my user after that.
Is there a way to achieve that using FlowRouter and Meteor? Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: Here is the code I use in `PrivateRoute.js`:

```
privateRoutes.route('/test', {
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('MainLayout', {
      main: 'test'
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(this).scrollTop(0);
    });
  },
  name: 'test',
});
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, you need to url-encode the current (RELATIVE!) route path as `queryParam`, attach it to your redirected login-page and on login success decode it and route to it using `FlowRouter.go`. Edit: look at how StackOverflow it does ;-)

Comment: The redirection to this specific page has to happen only after the user access the login page from the mail I sent - in case of another link, I want it to access the website main page normally. Is it the result I'll have following your solution?

Comment: Maybe you add some of your current code of the redirect and the login page, then I can point you in the right direction.